# Samba Share: smb doesn't set group id bit

Tags: linux, centos, samba, smb

I have some problems with a smb share. Every subfolder should get the group id bit. If I create a directory local on the machine with:

```
$ mkdir local
```

the bit is set, but if i create it via the smb share it is not set. now it looks like this:

```
$ ll
    total 8
    drwxrwsr-x 2 pat skynet 4096 Jul 23 23:03 local
    drwxrwxr-x 2 pat skynet 4096 Jul 23 23:03 smb
```

here is the part from the smb.conf where is set the share:

```
[pub]  
        comment = pub share
        path = /mnt/pub
        public = no
        browseable = yes
        writeable = yes
        valid users = +skynet
        directory mask = 775
```

any ideas?

Comment: I currently figured out that the problem only appears with mac os x clients. works fine with a windows xp machine.